# How many processes will be created fork() exec()

Tags: operating-system, fork, exec

I am new to Operating System and reading through my notes for my OS class and this is the question given. I was trying to calculate how many total processes created by reading to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106576/how-many-processes-are-created-with-these-fork-statements) discussion.

Question given:
How many processes will be created (INCLUDING THE PARENT) if
all the fork()/exec() system calls in the following program are successful. Assume
exec’ed program does no fork().

```
Main(){
    int ii = fork();
    if (ii == 0) exec();
    fork();
}
```

Answer:

The total number of processes = 3

Based on the discussion (page that I included above), I have the following processes

```
Main(){                  //Main program is consider as 1 process
    int ii = fork();     //fork #1, now I have 2 total processes
    if (ii == 0) exec(); 
    fork();              //fork #2, now I have 4 total processes
}
```

So do I have 4 processes instead of 3?

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 processes.

This is also easily verified in your favorite language with your favorite compiler. Just print something after your last fork.